# How to make watch directory service to monitor multiple folders

Tags: java, monitoring

JDK7's `java.nio.file` package has a `WatchService` to support file change notification. I am successful in monitoring one directory, but I have a `String` array containing directories that need monitoring in parallel (like `d:\channel1` `d:\channel2` `d:\channel3` `d:\channel4` `d:\channel5`).

Here in monitoring, we will pass the directory name and provide the infinite loop , so it keeps on watches the directory without closing the loop. But now I have a string of array which contains directories which needs to be monitored. But this directories are configured from XML and parsing it and getting the directory names, so in feature there might be increase or decrease the directories to be monitored (simply directories are dynamic based on the XML configuration). So I get those directories in String array. As this service is infinite loop, its not moving to next directory when i loop over the String array.

Below is the code where I loop over String array.

```
String[] path = parseXML.getOutDirNames();
for(String str : path){
    Path dir = Paths.get(str);
    new WatchDir(dir, true).processEvents();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. So you have a have an infinite loop that does what?

Comment: @MattiLyra to monitor the directories, one should implement using infinite loop. So it keeps on checking the directory unless the loop is breaked. As i have now number of paths to monitor in an String array, request is not moving to next index of array to monitor the directory.

Comment: @developer writing an infinite loop is definitely the wrong way to implement directory monitoring IMHO...

Comment: You should probably have a look at the `WatchService` tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html - you seem to have the complete wrong end of the stick

Comment: @MattiLyra ,Yahia in the link provided by Matti, under section "Watch Service Overview" check the 3rd point please, iam pointing to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was very happy that i fixed it by changing make above for loop to to infinite forloop

```
for(;;){
for(String str : path){
    Path dir = Paths.get(str);
    new WatchDir(dir, true).processEvents();
}
}
```